# ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(3,) and logits.shape=(7, 3)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

## My goal is to process all the text at once for both input & output.

Heres the summary.

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, None, 256)         3072

 dense (Dense)               (None, None, 250)         64250

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, None, 3)           753
=================================================================
Total params: 68075 (265.92 KB)
Trainable params: 68075 (265.92 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

OS: Win 10

Py version: 3.11.4

tf version: 2.13.0

Code:
`

```
import tensorflow as tf
text = "abcdefg xyz"
vocab = sorted(set(text)) # coverts all text to vocab for refrence.

ids_from_chars = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(vocab), mask_token=None)


chars_from_ids = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary(), invert=True, mask_token=None)


input = tf.strings.unicode_split("abcdefg", input_encoding='UTF-8')
output =  tf.strings.unicode_split("xyz", input_encoding='UTF-8')
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((input, output)) 




vocab_size = len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary())
embedding_dim = 256

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3) 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

`
I am new to TensorFlow & any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Flatten only works if you specify the input_length in the Embedding.
You need to slightly change your model architecture, now your output is 2D (7,3) and your labels are 1D (3), so the error was thrown because the loss will not be computed and these two shapes must be the same.
Add a flatten layer by:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=7),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3) 
])
```

Check your summary again.

Comment: Got the following error from your suggestion:
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None).

Comment: Because you did not specify the input_length in the Embedding layer

Comment: Never thought about length, but now im getting the following error from your suggestions:
 Input 0 of layer "dense_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1750, but received input with shape (7, 250)

Comment: Would you provide your model summary again.

Comment: Make sure your input data has the input_length.

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, verbose=2)
Where are your labels, you are not passing them in the training